# Making tables with alternating number of rows in cells

Tags: tables

[image]

I am trying to make the above table using the code given below.

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Result of transfer learning}
\label{tab2}
\begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|}

\hline
Model Name & Band/Model & Accuracy & Accuracy after voting \\
\hline
\multirow{3}{4em}{C1 vs C2} & alpha & 58.45\% \\ 
& beta & 60.01\% \\ 
& theta & 54.32\% \\

\hline

\multirow{3}{4em}{C1 vs C3} & alpha & 65.96\% \\ 
& beta & 67.02\% \\ 
& theta & 63.30\% \\ 

\hline

\multirow{3}{4em}{C3 vs C2} & alpha & 55.45\% \\ 
& beta & 64.28\% \\ 
& theta & 57.01\% \\ 

\hline


\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

But as you can see, it is not coming as I expected. There are basically two issues that I am facing.

1 - How do I add values to the right-most column ( Accuracy after voting column)? I have to only add one value in this column per row unlike three values in the columns before it which is why I am having problems.

2 - How do I close the bracket on the right end?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1 - How do I add values to the right-most column ( Accuracy after voting column)? I have to only add one value in this column per row unlike three values in the columns before it which is why I am having problems.

> 2 - How do I close the bracket on the right end?

For Q1, just use a `\multirow` directive in the final column -- akin to what you're doing in the first column. For Q2, just add extra `&` particles in the rows for which you don't already have a `\multirow` directive in column 4.

There are two additional issues. First, with fixed column widths there's no guarantee that the four-column table will fit inside the width of the text block. Thus, I'd like to suggest replace the `tabular` with a `tabularx` column. Second, since the table has quite a few `\multirow{3}{*}{...}` directives, I'd also recommend creating a shortcut macro, say,

```
 \newcommand\MR[1]{\multirow{3}{*}{#1}}
```

to simplify inputing the correspongding material.

The result of implementing these recommendations is shown in table 1 below.

Do note that the "look" of table 1 isn't exactly open and inviting. If a table isn't open and inviting, your readers are simly less likely to engage with the table's contents. I would therefore also like to recommend that you (a) get rid of all vertical rules and most horizontal rules and (b) use some of the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package  -- specifically: `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\bottomrule`, and `\addlinespace`. The result of implementing these additional recommendations is shown in Table 2 below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,multirow}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X}
\newcommand\MR[1]{\multirow{3}{*}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption} % optional
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{5} % just for this example

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Result of transfer learning, Take 1} \label{tab1}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{4}{L|}}
\hline
Model Name & Band\slash Model & Accuracy & Accuracy after voting \\
\hline
\MR{C1 vs C2} & alpha & 58.45\% & \MR{something} \\
   & beta  & 60.01\% & \\ 
   & theta & 54.32\% & \\
\hline
\MR{C1 vs C3} & alpha & 65.96\% & \MR{something} \\
   & beta  & 67.02\% & \\ 
   & theta & 63.30\% & \\ 
\hline
\MR{C3 vs C2} & alpha & 55.45\% & \MR{something} \\ 
   & beta  & 64.28\% & \\ 
   & theta & 57.01\% & \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Result of transfer learning, Take 2} \label{tab2}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} LCCC @{}}
\toprule
Model Name & Band\slash Model & Accuracy & Accuracy after voting \\
\midrule
\MR{C1 vs C2} & alpha & 58.45\% & \MR{something} \\
   & beta  & 60.01\% \\ 
   & theta & 54.32\% \\
\addlinespace
\MR{C1 vs C3} & alpha & 65.96\% & \MR{something} \\
   & beta  & 67.02\% \\ 
   & theta & 63.30\% \\ 
\addlinespace
\MR{C3 vs C2} & alpha & 55.45\% & \MR{something} \\ 
   & beta  & 64.28\% \\ 
   & theta & 57.01\% \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

- as is already mentioned, you always need to put all ampersants to table body that you will get last vertical line in table
- for column with numbers I would use `S` column type defined in the  `siunitx` package and `makecell` package for column header
- it is not clear, what is in the last column. A number, a text, just check mark? I consider the last possibility

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dingbat}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Result of transfer learning}
\label{tab2}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|S[table-format=2.2,
                       table-space-text-post=\,\%]|c|}
    \Xhline{1pt}
\makecell{Model\\ Name} 
    &   \makecell{Band/\\ Model}
        &   {\makecell{Accuracy}} 
            &   \makecell{Accuracy\\ after voting} \\
    \Xhline{0.7pt}
\multirow{3.4}*{C1 vs C2} 
    & alpha & 58.45\,\% & \multirow{3.4}{*}{\checkmark}   \\
    & beta  & 60.01\,\% &                         \\
    & theta & 54.32\,\% &                         \\
    \hline
\multirow{3.4}{*}{C1 vs C3} 
    & alpha & 65.96\,\% & \multirow{3.4}{*}{\checkmark}   \\
    & beta  & 67.02\,\% &                         \\
    & theta & 63.30\,\% &                         \\
    \hline
\multirow{3.4}{*}{C3 vs C2}
    & alpha & 55.45\,\% & \multirow{3.4}{*}{\checkmark}   \\
    & beta  & 64.28\,\% &                         \\
    & theta & 57.01\,\% &                         \\
    \Xhline{1pt}
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would go with `\multirow{3}{...}{...}`, not `\multirow{3.4}{...}{...}`.

Comment: @Mico, because I use `\makegapedcells` which introduce additional vertical  space in cells, the cell content in `\multirow{3.4}{...}{...}`  is better vertical centered. The same result is obtained by use of `\multirow{3}*[-2pt]{C1 vs C2}`, however I rather estimate this 2pt shift by decimal numbers of spanning text lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{multirow, makecell}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \centering
        \caption{Result of transfer learning}
        \label{tab2}
        \begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|}
            \hline
            Model Name & Band/Model & Accuracy & Accuracy after voting \\
            \hline
            \makecell{C1 vs C2} & \makecell{alpha\\beta\\theta} & \makecell{58.45\% \\60.01\%\\54.32\%}&z\\ 
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```